# Configuration issue adding AWStat to Apache v2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-7, configuration, cgi, awstats

I'm trying to add AWStats to my working Apache website.  But when I go to my perl script it fails:

```
http://localhost/awstats/awstats.pl?config=my.domain.here
```

I get this error 500 in the browser:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
```

I have the following error log entries

```
[Mon Feb 01 19:59:48 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (OS 2)The system cannot find the file specified.  : couldn't create child process: 720002: awstats.pl
[Mon Feb 01 19:59:48 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (OS 2)The system cannot find the file specified.  : couldn't spawn child process: C:/Program Files/AWStats/wwwroot/cgi-bin/awstats.pl
```

I thought it was maybe due to cgi not being enabled, so I added this to my config file:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/Program Files/AWStats/wwwroot/cgi-bin/"

<Directory "C:/Program Files/AWStats/wwwroot/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

But that didn't seem to help.  Note that AWStats inserted the following at the end of the config file:

```
Alias /awstatsclasses "C:/Program Files/AWStats/wwwroot/classes/"
Alias /awstatscss "C:/Program Files/AWStats/wwwroot/css/"
Alias /awstatsicons "C:/Program Files/AWStats/wwwroot/icon/"
ScriptAlias /awstats/ "C:/Program Files/AWStats/wwwroot/cgi-bin/"
```

Note that localhost seems to go to my first virtual entry:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\myDomain"
ServerName my.domain.here
Redirect /index.html http://my.domain.here/myDirectory
```

Please suggest what might be going wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you got Perl installed? AFAIK [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/) is the one everyone uses.

Comment: Yes, AWState refuses to install unless Perl is first installed.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the following additional things to get this working:

1) Activate CGI by adding to my Apache httpd.conf file the following options:

```
Options ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
```

2) Edit my Perl scripts to replace the default location of #!/usr/bin/perl with the one for my windows perl install: #!c:/Perl/bin/perl.exe

Then it worked!